# How to move the control to the else part of "if-else" when error comes in the statements under 'if' part?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to make condition such that if error comes in the statements/matrices under `if`  then  execute statements under `else`?

i.e .

```
if (some condition)
some statment1/matrix1/variable1 
some statement2/matrix2/variable2
some statement3/matrix3/variable3

else newstatement/matrix %come to else part of the code if any of the statements 1,2 or 3 under if condition yields any error like dimension mismatch or anyother
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No built-in mechanism to jump to `else` section. But you can use a construct like this:

```
condition_flag = (some condition);
error_flag = false;

if condition_flag
    try
        some statment1/matrix1/variable1 
        some statement2/matrix2/variable2
        some statement3/matrix3/variable3
    catch
        error_flag = true;
    end
end

if ~condition_flag || error_flag
    %if any of the statements 1,2 or 3 under if condition yields any error  like dimension mismatch or anyother
    ....
    error_flag = false;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to the one of Mohsen Nostrania.

```
else_flag=true;
if (condition)
  try
    %% The if code
    else_flag=false;
  end
end
if else_flag
  %% The else code
end
```

The `else_flag=false;` command is executed only when `condition` is true and no error occured within the `<if code>`.

Be aware that both solutions do literally what you want - the `<if code>` commands are executed until an error occur and then the `<else code>` is executed.

Comment: Your try-catch block is missing a catch statement

Comment: @Matt I know that. If you don't care about the error details you can suppress warning `missing catch statement` and ignore it. If the catch sequence shall be executed, the else code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If one want to reduce tre number of `if` statements:

```
try
  if statement
    %% The if code
  else
    %% Obvious error
    a(0);
  end
catch
  %% The else code
end
```